# Responsive menu doesn´t open (Bootstrap 2)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Please can anybody tell me why doesn´t open the responsive menú in mobile view?

http://garciarevuelta.com/contacto/index.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's because you didn't include the bootstrap.js file on your page.

The navbar works by calling [bootstrap's collapse function](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse) that uses the elements data attributes to know which element to show or hide.

I copied bootstrap's [collapse.js](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js) file into your page and the menu began working. So I'm sure all you need to do is add the file to your js directory and include this in your page

`<script src="../../contacto/quform/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`